# Reset the current form without reloading page?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

In our scenario, we have a form of several apex:inputfield elements and some other input fields. So they have a default value coming from database. We have implemented a cancel button which currently just reload the page to refresh the content. However, I do have a feeling this is low efficiency. I am trying to think about a way do reset the table without reloading the page.

One approach I can think of is to use an apex:actionfunction which can be called when pressing the button and loading the default values again from database then rerender the form. This approach will probably work (I haven't tried) but will still result in large view state. Is there a better (would prefer client side) way of doing this? No is an absolutely acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*prerequisite: jQuery; assumption: that you want this to be all client-side and capturing the values as they were initially rendered.*

This can be done pretty simply in JavaScript, using jQuery here for ease of implementation.

```
// array to hold our form's default values as they were rendered
var inputsArray = [];

// iterate the input types in the page and store the value of each of them in the array
function storeValues() {

    jQuery('input:text, textarea, input:checkbox').each(function() {



        var $formElement = jQuery(this),
            key = $formElement.attr('name'),
            value = $formElement.val();

        // capture the values in an array as a key/value pair, but make sure we have a key
        if (key) {
            inputsArray.push([key, value]);
        }

    });

    return false;
}

// iterate the array and set the value on each form element with the value from the array
function resetValues() {

    jQuery(inputsArray).each(function() {

        var $arrayElement = $(this),
            key = $arrayElement[0],
            value = $arrayElement[1];

        // set the value on the HTML form element, make sure we've got a key
        if (key) {
            jQuery("[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

// example usage
// on document.ready call "storeValues();"
// on cancel / reset button click call "return resetValues();"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just rerender that section of the page, calling an appropriate controller method to initialise the data for the fields, and probably use `immediate="true"` to skip any validation etc. that might be encountered in a semi-filled form.

Answer (score 2):

It's not straight forward in VF. You could use javascript and set all the value of your form to blank. It will be a bit faster and more responsive than using an actionFunction.

```
//using specific id
document.getElementById('{!$Component.myField}').value = '';
```

or

```
//get all the input
document.getElementByTagNames('input') and loop through all the elements.
```